# Can I Run PM2 on Parent or Root Directory?

Tags: node.js, microservices, pm2

I'm thinking if this approach is proper or can be done.

My directory goes like:

```
/root-folder
├─ /repo1
│  └─ /src
│     └─ index.js
├─ /repo2
│   └─ /src
│      └─ index.js
└─ ecosystem.config.js
```

This is the `ecosystem.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "Service1",
      cwd: "/root-folder",
      script: "./repo1/src/index.js",
    },
    {
      name: "Service2",
      cwd: "/root-folder",
      script: "./repo2/src/index.js",
    },
  ],
};
```

While pm2 starts and gets them both online, both ports are not working.

I've also tried and observed:

1. When doing pm2 on the `root-folder/repo1` with command `pm2 start src/index.js` the application works on the port.
2. But when doing pm2 on the `root-folder` with command `pm2 start repo1/src/index.js` the application does not work on the port.

The port only works when the `pm2 start` command is executed inside the repo folder, but if you run it on the parent or root folder. Nothing's pulling up.

The idea behind is I want to run pm2 ecosystem configs outside the server sources folders. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally I think this is a bad idea. PM2 already manages this for you automatically (the folder where all the configuration is saved is the `.pm2` folder in your user's home directory). Don't reinvent the wheel - you'll be unhappy and PM2 will be unhappy. Just do pm2 start twice in the two repos (they will both be managed by the same **ONE** instance of pm2). Once you have all services running properly run `pm2 save` to save your setup. To have all services automatically load when you reboot your machine run `pm2 startup` and follow the instructions on screen

Comment: @slebetman This totally make sense! Haha. I never thought it will go to the same pm2 instance. When I did the `pm2 monit` it's all there. Haha. Thanks so much for this! No need for parent dir at all.

Comment: @slebetman I don't know how to mark your comment as the answer. But yeah, this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I can write it as the answer if you like but I just left a comment because: 1. Didn't think it needed too much explaining since it's all in the docs and 2. Too lazy to format it properly as an answer

Comment: okay all good, thanks much @slebetman :)